# how to change images to keep scrollbar's position?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

It's a chat room, I can get list of data including text, images and voice, 20 list at most.
At first, i set default src, height to these images tags to get body's height because it must scroll to bottom when the chat room opened. But when I get the real image, i change all after.
So, here is the problems.**Changing 'scrollTop' frequently makes the 'viewport' shake** .Is anybody has similar experience and the solution??
thanks
Here is my way:[use 'onload' event to get real height first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCsJx.png)

```
function ReplacePicture (imgid, url) {
  var $img = $('#img-'+imgid);
  var oldH = parseInt($img.css('height'));
  $img.attr('oldHeight', oldH);
  $img.attr('src', url);
  $img.on('load', function() {
    var oldH = $(this).attr('oldHeight');
    var newH = $(this).css('height').match(/\d+/g);
    if (newH == oldH) return;
    oldH = parseInt(oldH);
    newH = parseInt(newH);
    var changeH = newH - oldH;
    $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop() + changeH);
    $(this).attr('oldHeight',newH);
  });
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: When i get the real imgs ,I set height 300px,and everytime i change a picture to get the height`var changeHeight = realImgSize.height - oldImgSize.height;
      $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop()+changeHeight);` but, i dont want to set imgs height 300px now